# is that possible to select directly and view results in sql server on objects generated by tfs2013 web access?

Tags: sql, web-services, select, sql-server-2012

I found tfs 2013 web access fail to export history data to excel. So I have to retrieve history data programmatically by call `workItemStore.Query(select * from workitems)` and get all the work items. Then iterate each revision of each work item to get revision fields.

Since I need to add some `where` statements to filter result(the whole work items collection), and Microsoft has offered the Query() function, I wonder if I can write a select query directly in the database of this tfs2013 web? if I can do that, it will be much more convenient for me to check my query results maybe some future work.

Though IT told me I cannot because of Encapsulation.

My tfs is 2013 web access, sql server is 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly query the SQL Server then you have to use the TFS_Warehouse database (assuming that you used the default values during installation). For tables reference you can check in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244691.aspx)

Or you can use PowerShell to access the work items store. See example [here](https://blog.andrewhuey.com/2015/03/tfs-query-powershell-script/)